# Uncaught TypeError: options is not a function - SSRS (only in Google Chrome)

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I was using "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0" in my ASP.NET web forms application.

In the report viewer, after I clicked "View Report" button, I was getting below JavaScript error only on Google Chrome. I do not see any problem in Mozilla Firefox or Internet Explorer.

May I know why I have this error and how can I get this fixed?

```
Uncaught TypeError: options is not a function
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._Toolbar.SetUIToCurrentZoomLevel (Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=12.0.2402.15&Name=ViewerScript:5062)
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._Toolbar.UpdateForNewReportPage (Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=12.0.2402.15&Name=ViewerScript:4928)
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._Toolbar.OnReportAreaContentChanged (Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=12.0.2402.15&Name=ViewerScript:4835)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=fG_WoGPVtvzjOZg-NP_dufNAiVPwj-qauWYNYRKo6o_E16L_8ayZvvi8ykZNd_AXLvdwMWZshkfEUG…:47)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=fG_WoGPVtvzjOZg-NP_dufNAiVPwj-qauWYNYRKo6o_E16L_8ayZvvi8ykZNd_AXLvdwMWZshkfEUG…:3484
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer.Sys$Component$raisePropertyChanged [as raisePropertyChanged] (ScriptResource.axd?d=fG_WoGPVtvzjOZg-NP_dufNAiVPwj-qauWYNYRKo6o_E16L_8ayZvvi8ykZNd_AXLvdwMWZshkfEUG…:3701)
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer._onReportAreaContentChanged (Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=12.0.2402.15&Name=ViewerScript:5411)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=fG_WoGPVtvzjOZg-NP_dufNAiVPwj-qauWYNYRKo6o_E16L_8ayZvvi8ykZNd_AXLvdwMWZshkfEUG…:47)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=fG_WoGPVtvzjOZg-NP_dufNAiVPwj-qauWYNYRKo6o_E16L_8ayZvvi8ykZNd_AXLvdwMWZshkfEUG…:3484
    at Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient._InternalReportViewer.Sys$Component$raisePropertyChanged [as raisePropertyChanged] (ScriptResource.axd?d=fG_WoGPVtvzjOZg-NP_dufNAiVPwj-qauWYNYRKo6o_E16L_8ayZvvi8ykZNd_AXLvdwMWZshkfEUG…:3701)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to update to the latest version of the Report Viewer Control - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/11/30/report-viewer-2016-control-update-now-available/